# Probability function of camera's photon detection

Tags: distributions, poisson-distribution

My lab utilizes a RGB camera we are trying to characterize. Especially, we are interested in the light intensity distribution. Photon detection is typically modelled by a Poisson distribution which has the same expectation value and variance. To test, if this can also be applied in our case we captured 100 images of the same sample to get a statistic of the measured light intensities. A broad range of intensities was available. From these 100 images we calculated the pixelwise expectation values as the mean value and the standard deviations. Then the relationship between expectation value and variance was determined by least squares fitting as $\sigma^2=3\mu $.

This can clearly no longer be modelled by a simple Poissonian distribution. As I am not an expert in statistics, I would be greateful for any tips which distribution we could use instead. As our intensities are large ($I\gg10$), they can probably be modelled by a normal distribution, but still for a comparison we want to know the actual distribution.
The distribution we are looking for should fulfill:

1. $\sigma^2=3\mu $
2. Defined on natural numbers as light intensities are only positive integers

From what I see, it must be some kind of super Poisson distribution. The only analytical form I found is from

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1245024/is-there-a-analytical-formula-for-super-and-sub-poissonian-distributions

where the following distribution is proposed:

$$ P(x)=\frac{(\alpha\mu)^{\frac{x}{\alpha}}}{\left(\frac{x}{\alpha}\right)!}e^{-\mu\alpha} $$

but the claimed $\langle x\rangle=\mu$ and $\langle(\Delta x)^2\rangle=\frac{\mu}{\alpha}$ do not seem correct when the distribution is plotted.

Any other ideas are welcome :)

Comment: The formula from the Math site looks correct: it simply says that $X/\alpha$ has a Poisson$(\alpha\mu)$ distribution.  However, it's inapplicable to your situation because it's not a distribution supported on the natural numbers.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification.
I plotted two distributions with wolfram alpha. Normal Poisson distribution with exp. val. 3000: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3000%5Ex*e%5E(-3000)%2F(x!)+from+2750+to+3250

Modified Poisson distribution wih shape parameter 1/3: 
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+1000%5E(1%2F3*x)*e%5E(-1000)%2F((1%2F3*x)!)+from+2750+to++3250

The modified version obviously has a larger variance but the maximum of the distribution is not exactly 3000, but 2998.5

Comment: Don't confuse the location of the maximum (known as the *mode*) with the mean.